# Is there a way to load a scene after a small delay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a topdown ARPG game that involves a coroutine for a spawner function for the delay between spawns. However when you beat the level, I have it set up to stop the coroutine in order for the enemies to stop spawning. Then it fades back to the main scene. However my code fades but does not end up transitioning

```
[SerializeField]
private float spawnDelay = 0, spawnTimerLength = 0;
[SerializeField]
private float lowSpawnX = 0, highSpawnX = 0, lowSpawnY = 0, highSpawnY = 0;
public GameObject enemy;
float timeToLoadScene = 10f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("SpawnEnemy");        
}
void Update()
{
    if (spawnTimerLength > 0)
    {
        spawnTimerLength -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        Player.instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        UIController.instance.pauseButton.SetActive(false);
        UIController.instance.healthImage.SetActive(false);
        UIController.instance.hpbarImage.SetActive(false);
        UIController.instance.StartFadeToBlack();
        Invoke("GoToScene", timeToLoadScene);
    }
}
void GoToScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
}
IEnumerator SpawnEnemy()
{
    float SpawnPointX = Random.Range(lowSpawnX, highSpawnX);
    float SpawnPointY = Random.Range(lowSpawnY, highSpawnY);
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(SpawnPointX, SpawnPointY, 0);
    Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay);
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemy());
}
```

}
Since my code uses StopAllCoroutines in order to stop the spawner, I am unable to use coroutines in order to set another delay for the fade. However, I tried using invoke to set a delay on a function that transitions scenes, but for some reason it does not work. Thank you for any suggestions, I have tried working on this for 2 hours.

Comment: check if the method `GoToScene()` is being called and take it out of the update where it is called multiple times instead of only 1.

Comment: And why don't you only stop the one Coroutine for the spawn then?

Comment: I tried using that at first but it never worked so I worked around that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the GoToScene in the update loop. Try either creating a separate timer that gets managed in your update loop (not using the Invoke method). Or create a boolean flag to only call the GoToScenes once in your Invoke method.

Comment: I combined both your and Daniel's solution. I created a conditional timer thats written below while using the aspects of the Update function ' if (timeToLoadScene > 0)
            {
                timeToLoadScene -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");

            } '

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above I used a conditional statement that was much simpler code and utilized a simple timer.
`if (timeToLoadScene > 0)
{
timeToLoadScene -= Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");

```
        }`
```